Giving/calculating explicit homomorphism between fundamental groups
I'm not sure how to approach this problem exactly, and what is meant by it.

Let $M$ be the Möbius strip. Determine the homomorphism $\iota_{*} \colon \pi_{1}(S^{1}, 0) \rightarrow \pi_{1}(M, (0,0))$ for
\begin{equation*}\iota \colon S^{1} \rightarrow M \colon \theta \mapsto \begin{cases}(2\theta, 0) & \theta \in [0, \frac{1}{2}] \newline (2\theta -1, 1) & \theta \in [\frac{1}{2}, 1]\end{cases}\end{equation*}

I know the definition of said induced homomorphism: it would map an equivalence class $[f]\in \pi_{1}(S^{1}, 0)$ of a loop $f$ to $[\iota \circ f]$. I don't know how to proceed. Perhaps I'm overlooking something, or I should better understand what the homomorphism does exactly. Any help is appreciated.

What is the topological space $M$?

My bad! It is the Mobius strip/band, I’ve edited the post.

The (implicit) question is to express $\iota_*$ as an explicit group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$, since we know that $\pi_1(S^1, 0) \cong \mathbb{Z} \cong \pi_1(M, (0, 0))$.

@NaïmFavier Right, I know that if $\iota_{}$ is said homomorphism then $\iota_{}(x) = nx$ for some integer $n$. Is this the correct approach? If so, how would I determine $n$?

Think about how $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ is mapped to $\pi_1(S^1)$, how that is mapped to $\pi_1(M)$, and how that is mapped back to $\mathbb{Z}$.

@NaïmFavier Since $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi_{1}(S^{1})$ are isomorphic we know the generators are mapped to each other: $1$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ is mapped to the loop that goes around $S^{1}$ once. But I don’t see how this is mapped to $\pi_{1}(M)$.

You gave the definition of $\iota_* : \pi_1(S^1) \to \pi_1(M)$ yourself.

@NaïmFavier Right, so if we parametrize the path in $S^{1}$ by $\gamma(t) = e^{2\pi i\theta}$ and proceed as you said. We get a path that goes around the Mobius strip once, which generates $\pi_{1}(M)$. Hence it is mapped to $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ under isomorphism, and $n=1$ for $\iota_{*}$. Is that correct? Sorry if this discussion is a bit long.

No. You need to compute $\iota \circ \gamma$.
